# Сравнить два listBox

Tags: c#

Как сравнить listBox1 с listBox2 если данные не подходят выводить их на экран?

Я пробовал так, но не получается:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items[i] != listBox2.Items[i])
        {
            listBox3.Items.Add(listBox2.Items[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: распишите подробнее как именно нужно сравнить элементы. Пока вы пытаетесь сравнивать элементы с одинаковыми номерами без учета что во втором списке их может быть меньше, что закономерно должно заканчиваться OutOfRangeException

Comment: @Sauron, то есть вам нужно проверить каждый элемент первого `ListBox` со всеми элементами второго `ListBox`? Если они не совпадают то добавить в третий `LisstBox`?

Answer (score 3):

Так как не понятно какие типы у вас хранятся в `ListBox`, то предположу что там `string`. Воспользуемся операцией `Except`, которая возвращает последовательность, содержащую все элементы первой последовательности, которых нет во второй последовательности.

```
var exceptItems = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Except(listBox2.Items.Cast<string>()); 

foreach(string s in exceptItems)
     listBox3.Items.Add(s);
```